# EclipseGavab: erro ao compilar arquivo .pas

Tags: eclipse, instalador, pascal, configuração, binary

Instalei Freepascal 32bits
e Instalei o Eclipse Gavab 32bits

Porém esta dando erro!

[image: Erro ao compilar arquivo .pas]

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Tem o link para baixar ele?

Comment: Eu baixei neste link: http://www.escet.urjc.es/~smontalvo/resources/UsoEclipseGavab.pdf

Comment: E tem este tutorial aqui: http://www.escet.urjc.es/~smontalvo/resources/UsoEclipseGavab.pdf

Comment: Alguma configuração ???

Comment: Não estou conseguindo gerar os arquivos binários....

Comment: Fiz um teste com essa [instalação](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j8lpns99n6r2unk/umQrLC1t2Y/EclipseGavab-2.0-win.msi) funcionou corretamente, parece que ele já instala tudo.

Comment: Ok! Faltou Debug no projeto...Sem isso não existe os arquivos binários.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.
Basta Gerar os arquivos binários antes de compilar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]